# create a function of a repetitive else if

Tags: php

the question title might not justify my question at all since I have no idea what to write as the title.

So, if I have something like this:

```
if($type=="a"){
    $s.= " AND type= 'List Apart ";
}elseif($type=="b"){
    $s.= " AND type = 'Before CSS3' ";
}elseif($type=="C"){
    $s.= " AND type = 'Tricks' ";
}elseif($type=="D"){
    $s.= " AND type = 'Stackoverflow' ";

.. etc until Z (just for example)
```

So can I do this? I've tried it but it doesn't work.

```
$arr = array("b"=>"Before CSS3",..."Z"=>"Somethingd"); // it's not just a simple a-z. A is hardcoded because of the if.
    foreach($arr as $r){
        $r.= "}elseif($type=='key($r)'){   //not the syntax cos I kinda forget :p
        $s.= ' AND type = \'value($r)\' "; //same here
    }
    return $r;
```

UPDATE : Sorry if I was not being clear enough, I've already edited my question. So it's not just a simple a-z loop, it's an array with keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exact values your "types" can have and what they map to. For your example, you could just write this:

```
$s .= " AND type = '" . strtoupper($type) . "' ";
```

No if statements needed. But if the types are different from the types you need to insert into your SQL query, try making an associative array and indexing into it with your `$type` variable:

```
$types = array(
  'a' => 'A',
  'b' => 'B',
  'c' => 'C',
  'd' => 'D'
);

$s .= " AND type = '" . $types[$type] . "' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more explicit with the data you work on, because based on your example you could simply do:

```
if(!empty($type)) {
  $s .= "AND type = '$type'"
}
```

Edit:

Or maybe this was your intent?

```
if(in_array($type, range('a','z'))) {
  $s .= "AND type = '$type'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the type is gonna a lower case A-Z and you need to include the criteria as Upper case A-z why not try something like:

```
if(!empty($type))
{
    $s .= " AND type= '" . strtoupper($type) . "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if(strlen($type) == 1 && $type >= 'A' && $type <= 'Z') {
   $s.= " AND type = '$type' ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s .= " AND type= '".strtoupper($type)."'";
```